# Regular expression for percentage

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following RegExp which verifies the value to be 100%

```
(^100([.]0{1,2})?)$|(^\\d{1,2}([.]\\d{1,2})?)$
```

I'm trying to get it to accept percentages without the leading zero, example

`.5` rather than just `0.5`.

If someone could help me to correct this expression so that it would accept both, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What about leading zeroes on the integer part, like `03` or `00`?  Your current regex matches those, too.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=percent&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) you should find your correct regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `^([.]\d{1,2})?)` as another possible string:

```
(^100([.]0{1,2})?)$|(^\d{1,2}([.]\d{1,2})?)$|(^([.]\d{1,2})?)$
```